# subscribe' does not exist on type angular 6

Tags: angular

I am currently upgrading angular 4 to angular 6 code. I am getting error saying Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(o: NavigationEnd) => Observable | UnaryFunction, Observable<[{}, string, ...'

Its a syntatical error and do not understand why i am getting it

Existing Code

```
@Injectable()
export class TitleService {
    constructor(private _config: ConfigService, private _title: Title, private _translate: TranslateService, private _router: Router) {
        this._router.events.filter(o => o instanceof NavigationEnd).flatMap((o: NavigationEnd) => {
            if (!o.urlAfterRedirects.startsWith('/run/') || o.urlAfterRedirects.indexOf('~') > -1)
                return this._translate.get('CURRENT_MODEL.TITLE');
            else {
                const url = o.urlAfterRedirects.substring(1)/*skip starting slash*/.split('/').slice(2);
                let list = this._config.runPages;
                let find = this._config.runPages[0];
                for (let i = 0; i < url.length; ) {
                    const index = list.findIndex(rp =>
                        rp.identifier.split('/').every((part, index2) =>
                            part.startsWith(':') || part === url[i + index2])
                    );

                    if (index === -1) throw new Error(url[i] + ' not found in run page hierarchy');
                    find = list[index];

                    list = find.children || [];
                    i += find.identifier.split('/').length;
                }
                return Rx.Observable.zip(this._translate.get('CURRENT_MODEL.TITLE'), this._translate.get(`CURRENT_MODEL.RUN_PAGES.${find.displayTitle.toUpperCase()}`)).map(r => `${r[0]} - ${r[1]}`);
            }
        }).subscribe(ret => this._title.setTitle(ret));
    }
}
```

Modified Code

```
export class TitleService {
    constructor(private _config: ConfigService, private _title: Title, private _translate: TranslateService, private _router: Router) {
        this._router.events.pipe(filter(o => o instanceof NavigationEnd)).pipe(flatMap(((o: NavigationEnd) => {
            if (!o.urlAfterRedirects.startsWith('/run/') || o.urlAfterRedirects.indexOf('~') > -1)
                return  (<Observable<string>>this._translate.get('CURRENT_MODEL.TITLE'));
            else {
                const url = o.urlAfterRedirects.substring(1)/*skip starting slash*/.split('/').slice(2);
                let list = this._config.runPages;
                let find = this._config.runPages[0];
                for (let i = 0; i < url.length; ) {
                    const index = list.findIndex(rp =>
                        rp.identifier.split('/').every((part, index2) =>
                            part.startsWith(':') || part === url[i + index2])
                    );

                    if (index === -1) throw new Error(url[i] + ' not found in run page hierarchy');
                    find = list[index];

                    list = find.children || [];
                    i += find.identifier.split('/').length;
                }
                return Rx.pipe(zip((<Observable<string>>this._translate.get('CURRENT_MODEL.TITLE')),  (<Observable<string>>this._translate.get(`CURRENT_MODEL.RUN_PAGES.${find.displayTitle.toUpperCase()}`)).pipe(map(r => `${r[0]} - ${r[1]}`))));
            }
        }).subscribe(ret => this._title.setTitle(ret))));
    }
}
```

Comment: RXJS 5 to 6 had some changes you should google on that.

Comment: I have made the changes as per my understanding . The changes mostly added are pipes but I am still getting syntax issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RxJS 6, you need to import the operators you want and use a pipe to make Observables work. This was done to enable tree shaking and you can read more about it on the official site.

For your use case, the following snippet with the correct imports should work.

```
@Injectable()
export class TitleService {
    constructor(private _config: ConfigService, private _title: Title, private _translate: TranslateService, private _router: Router) {
        this._router.events.pipe(
            filter(o => o instanceof NavigationEnd),
            flatMap((o: NavigationEnd) => {
                if (!o.urlAfterRedirects.startsWith('/run/') || o.urlAfterRedirects.indexOf('~') > -1)
                    return this._translate.get('CURRENT_MODEL.TITLE');
                else {
                    const url = o.urlAfterRedirects.substring(1)/*skip starting slash*/.split('/').slice(2);
                    let list = this._config.runPages;
                    let find = this._config.runPages[0];
                    for (let i = 0; i < url.length; ) {
                        const index = list.findIndex(rp =>
                            rp.identifier.split('/').every((part, index2) =>
                                part.startsWith(':') || part === url[i + index2])
                        );

                        if (index === -1) throw new Error(url[i] + ' not found in run page hierarchy');
                        find = list[index];

                        list = find.children || [];
                        i += find.identifier.split('/').length;
                    }
                    return Rx.Observable.zip(this._translate.get('CURRENT_MODEL.TITLE'), this._translate.get(`CURRENT_MODEL.RUN_PAGES.${find.displayTitle.toUpperCase()}`)).map(r => `${r[0]} - ${r[1]}`);
                }
            })
        ).subscribe(ret => this._title.setTitle(ret));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are mismatched—your second `pipe` call envelops the `subscribe` call later.  You need to fix up the parentheses.

Comment: When If i remove one parenthesis from second pipe, I still get syntactical error

Comment: Yes, because now you won't have a matching number of opening & closing parentheses!  Your best bet is probably to go with [nipuna777's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387843/4877269), which seems to have been derived from the original working code.

Comment: In your original code, your `subscribe` line ends with two closing brackets.  In your modified code, it ends with four.  There should be no change to the number of closing brackets on this line, because your `subscribe` call has not changed in any way.  Your IDE has really, really failed you here.